# Count logical lines of code with git

Tags: git

Is there a way to count the logical lines of code of a c++/java project with git? In addition I need to count them for author as well. Any tips?

Comment: You can maybe do a first commit and git will tell you the number of lines of code.

Comment: Why "with git"? No, `git` itself offers nothing of the sort.  You can do it with a dedicated tool outside of `git`.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Is it an attempt to measure productivity?

Comment: @Schwern Yes, it is.

Comment: Source Lines Of Code (SLOC) surviving in the end product is a [very bad measure of productivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code#Disadvantages). Don't do it, it will give you a completely distorted view. Measuring deltas (lines created *and* deleted in each commit) would be *slightly* better. Number of commits merged into master is better. Or number of tasks/issues/bugs completed. What you really want to know is each developer's [velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_%28software_development%29), and that's a whole other topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking at the current commit leave out the bracketed statements.

The following command counts all lines in the project.

```
[commit=<some-commit>]
for file in $(git ls-files [--with-tree=$commit])
do 
  git cat-file -p [$commit]:$file
done | 
wc -l
```

The following command will count all lines by author.

```
[commit=<some-commit>]
for file in $(git ls-files [--with-tree=$commit])
do 
  git blame [$commit] --line-porcelain -- $file
done | 
sed -n 's/^author //p' | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sort -r
```

Thanks to the [the Git documentation for git blame](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) for the counting of author lines per file. You can scrape other useful information as well if you modify the field you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to count the logical lines of code of a c++/java project with git?

Short answer?  No.  Git has no special understanding of the code.  There are tools which do, and you can simply run them on a checkout.

> I need to count them for author as well.

You can use `git blame` to tell you who wrote what line, but these will not be logical lines.  A single statement split across multiple lines will be counted multiple times.